# Why is my show function not working in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Below is the code in my route

```
Route::get('patients/{$patient}/','PatientController@show');
```

The above will not work in my browser , it will say 404 | not found with the url

below http://127.0.0.1:8000/patients/3

But

if I change my route to code below

```
Route::get('patients','PatientController@show');
```

I will not get any error , infact it will display the view for me.

What could be the problem? I am using Laravel 5.8

Comment: What does your `show()` method look like?

Comment: public function show(Patient $patient){

     echo "I am here";
     //$patient= Patient::where('id', $patient->id)->first();
     //dd($patient);
     //exit();
     //return view('patients.show',['patient'=>'$patient']);
     
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your route, `{$patient}` should be `{patient}`.

```
Route::get('patients/{patient}/','PatientController@show');
```

Then using model-route-binding, you will have the `$patient` model ready for you in your `show()` method,

```
public function show(Patient $patient){ 
    return view('patients.show', ['patient' => '$patient']); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks , the type in the router caused it, Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

This is your `route` problem.

```
Route::get('/patients/{patient?}',         'PatientController@show');
```

You can use url like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/patients/3
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/patients
```

And your controller is also simple

```
public function show(Patient $patient=null){ 
    return view('patients.show',compact('patient')); 
}
```